# jQuery fadeIn then fadeOut text from innerHTML not working

Tags: html, jquery

I have a jQuery function to fade text in and out one by one. However the function is not working correctly due to I place the text from jQuery. When I try to run it, it is only showing `0`. `1` to `4` is not shown.

```js
var html = '<div id="main">';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  html += '<div class="trip">' + i + '<div>';
}
html += '</div>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

var $elem = $('#main .trip'),
  l = $elem.length,
  i = 0;

function go() {
  $elem.eq(i % l).fadeIn(700, function() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).fadeOut(700, go);
    i++;
  })
}

go()
```

```css
.trip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todayPrayTime"></div>
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2vrmfdh6/)

Comment: Since you do `i++;` I believe that you want to run `go` in an interval or a loop, right? But there are no such function in your code..

Comment: @MoshFeu yes exactly. So what need to do?

Comment: I just noticed that you do it in loop (call `go` after the `fadeOut`). The issue is simpler - when you build the html you are not closing the `div`s but create a new one, so `html += '<div class="trip">' + i + '<div>';` should be `html += '<div class="trip">' + i + '</div>';`

Comment: Always use the browser tools to check what has been built (or `console.log($("#main").html())`) - your `.trip` divs are nested (due to typo as mentioned above)

Comment: I have to say that your approach is better than the answer and more readable. This is my opinion. (With all the respect to the answerer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var html = '<div id="main">';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  html += '<div class="trip">' + i + '</div>';
}
html += '</div>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

function go($list, i) {
  var l = $list.length, $trip = $list.eq(i % l);
  $trip.show().fadeIn(700, function(){
    $trip.fadeOut(700, function(){
       $trip.hide();
       if ( ++i < l ) go($list, i);
    });
  })
 }

go($('#main .trip'), 0)
```

```css
.trip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todayPrayTime"></div>
```

```js
var html = '<div id="main">';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  html += '<div class="trip">' + i + '</div>';
}
html += '</div>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

function go($list, i) {
  var l = $list.length, $trip = $list.eq(i);
  $trip.show().fadeIn(700, function(){
    $trip.fadeOut(700, function(){
       $trip.hide();
       go($list, (++i) % l);
    });
  })
 }

go($('#main .trip'), 0)
```

```css
.trip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todayPrayTime"></div>
```

Comment: No extra code needed except closing the `div` (like you did)

Comment: Hi @Nikos any way to do this always repeat?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave, updated, simply remove the test to check if i is the last index and you got it